# How do I make this div responsive in height?

Tags: responsive-design

How do I make this div responsive in height ?

```
<style>
.full1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
}
.left1,
.middle1, 
.right1 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height:100%;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div class="full1">
    <div class="left1" >
      <img class="left-image" src="http://s16.postimg.org/nc57l3p8l/1_screen_shot_2014_08_24_at_12_43_26_pm_medium.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="middle1">
      <img class="left-image" src="http://s16.postimg.org/wl7dv7y4l/windows_9_logo_01_medium.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="right1">
      <img class="right1-image" src="http://s16.postimg.org/ig6675eh1/windows_9_logo_08_medium.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k07gg3pv/.

The images get resized by width but the height leaves large blank space when zoomed.

Comment: http://siebennull.com/equal_width_height.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width / height for the images:

```
.full1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

(here is your fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/k07gg3pv/3/)

This will make the images fit exactly. But this isn't a good solution because your images won't have the proportions they should have. So you have to decide whether you want to fit exactly 100% in width or exactly the height, you won't get proper images and both.

So you have to set one value (width or height) for the images:

```
.full1 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

(here is your fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/k07gg3pv/4/)

Comment: No other way ? Maybe with background images ?

Comment: If you know that the width is always greater than the height, you could set height to 100%, create a parent-element and use `overflow` so the image gets cutted at the right side... But if you want to have them fit exactly and will keep their proportions there is now way to make it work, I'm sorry.

Comment: Disregard, I clicked on the first fiddle and not the second.